# VBA : How to change the cell's value in a function?

Tags: vba, function, excel

I'm a new vba programmer and I have some trouble.

This is my function :

```
Function CopiePaste(CASEREF As Range, REF)

Dim o As Range

For Each o In CASEREF

   o.Value = REF

Next

End Function
```

I want define multiple cell's value in a function but my code doesn't work and I don't understand why ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *VBA,* you would use a **Sub** rather than a **Function**

Here is one way that a **Sub** could use a **Function** to accomplish this:

```
Sub MAIN()
    Dim MSG As String
    MSG = CopiePaste(Range("A1:A10"), 123)
    MsgBox MSG
End Sub


Function CopiePaste(CASEREF As Range, REF) As Variant
    Dim o As Range
    For Each o In CASEREF
       o.Value = REF
    Next
    CopiePaste = "Mission Accomplished!"
End Function
```

*Note:  the custom function does not actually appear in a cell, but rather is called from the sub.*

Comment: Thank you, it helps me to understand how to program !

Answer (score 1):

I will make some suggestions but I am not an expert either :-) 
First: a function is supposed to return a value to the place in the code where the function is called from. 
Here, you want to do something instead of returning a value, so you should use a sub() instead of a function.

Second, I think you should also declare the "REF" variable for it to work, (unless if it's a public variable).